# Select statement with multiple rows based if columns are not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select statement that selects records with certain columns (`contact1_name`, `contact2_name` , `contact3_name` ) that can be null.
If the columns are NOT null, I want it to show as a new row.

Currently I have:

```
select
    table_1.id, table_1.fname, table_1.lname, table2.room,
    table_3.contact1,
    table_3.contact2,
    table_3.contact3,
FROM
    table_1
left join table_2
    on table_1.room = table_2.id
left join table_3
    on table_3.cid = table_1.id
where 
    table_1.location = 1
and 
    table_1.room in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

Which will result in something like this:

```
id  |  fname | lname | room | contact1 | contact2 | contact3
 1  |  John  | Smith | r_1  |  Bill    |  George  |
 2  |  Gerry | Name  | r_2  |  Harry   |          | 
 3  |  Will  | Gates | r_2  |  Steve   |  Hannah  |  Stacy
 4  |  Peter | Pall  | r_3  |          |          |
```

Instead, if `contact1`,`contact2` or `contact3` is not `null`, I want it to appear in a new row:

```
id  |  fname | lname | room | contact  
 1  |  John  | Smith | r_1  |  Bill    
 1  |  John  | Smith | r_1  |  George  
 2  |  Gerry | Name  | r_2  |  Harry   
 3  |  Will  | Gates | r_2  |  Steve   
 3  |  Will  | Gates | r_2  |  hannah  
 3  |  Will  | Gates | r_2  |  Stacy
```

Is this possible?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: check this url. it might help with approach https://www.sqlshack.com/the-difference-between-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use conditionals.

```sql
select
    table_1.id, table_1.fname, table_1.lname, table2.room,
    CASE
       WHEN table3.contact1 is not null THEN table3.contact1
       WHEN table3.contact2 is not null THEN table3.contact2
       WHEN table3.contact3 is not null THEN table3.contact3
       ELSE null
    END as contact
FROM
    table_1
left join table_2
    on table_1.room = table_2.id
left join table_3
    on table_3.cid = table_1.id
where 
    table_1.location = 1
and 
    table_1.room in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

UPDATE:
This will only pick the contact that's not null. If you want to get all non-null contacts on a new row, do this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (select table_1.id, table_1.fname, table_1.lname, table2.room,
CASE
       WHEN id_rank = 1 THEN contact1
       WHEN id_rank = 2 THEN contact2
       WHEN id_rank = 3 THEN contact3
    END as contact

FROM 

(
select
    table_1.id, table_1.fname, table_1.lname, table2.room,
    table_3.contact1, table3.contact2, table_3.contact3, dense_rank() over ( partition by table3.id order by table_1.id asc ) 
       as "id_order"
FROM
    table_3 left join 
    table_1 on table_3.cid = table_1.id
left join table_2
    on table_1.room = table_2.id

where 
    table_1.location = 1
and 
    table_1.room in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
) as sub_query

)
  as main_query

WHERE contact is NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Is it possible to return multiple columns if a condition is true? Something like:
```WHEN table3.contact1 is not null THEN table3.contact1, table3.contact1_number```

Comment: You can use a string function to concat them

Comment: Sorry for the many edits. I'm not used to mysql like postgres. I haven't really tested it but this idea should work.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select
    table_1.id
    , table_1.fname
    , table_1.lname
    , table2.room
    , t3.contact
FROM  table_1
left join table_2  on table_1.room = table_2.id
left join 
(
  select cid, contact1 as contact from table3
  union all 
  select cid, contact2 from table3
  union all 
  select cid, contact3 from table3
) t3 on t3.cid = table_1.id
where table_1.location = 1
  and table_1.room in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

As only three contact column in a sample table So I use union instead of PIVOT table or any other alternatives.

```
SELECT t.id, t.fname, t.lname, t.room, t.contact
FROM ( SELECT id, fname, lname, room, contact1 contact, 1 con_seq
       FROM table_name
       WHERE contact1 IS NOT NULL

       UNION ALL

       SELECT id, fname, lname, room, contact2 contact, 2 con_seq
       FROM table_name
       WHERE contact2 IS NOT NULL

       UNION ALL

       SELECT id, fname, lname, room, contact3 contact, 3 con_seq
       FROM table_name
       WHERE contact3 IS NOT NULL ) t
ORDER BY t.id, t.con_seq;
```